# Realize a $K_0$-group homomorphism by a unital $\ast$-homomorphism

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, c-star-algebras

This question is inspired by Exercise $7.7$ in *An Introduction to $K$-theory for $C^*$-algebras (available [here](https://wiki.math.ntnu.no/_media/ma8107/2014h/rordam_m.pdf)). Given a unital AF-algebra $A$ and another unital $C^*$-algebra $B$ that has cancellation property, let $\alpha: \big( K_0(A), K_0(A)^+, [1_A]_0 \big) \rightarrow \big( K_0(B), K_0(B)^+, [1_B]_0 \big)$ be a positive unit-preserving group homomorphism where $1_A$ is the unit of $A$ and $1_B$ is the unit of $B$. Can we find a unital $\ast$-homomorphism $\varphi: A\rightarrow B$ such that $K_0(\varphi) = \alpha$? In the original question $B$ is AF but based on the hint I am not convinced that this condition is necessary.

All definitions you need could be found in the textbook. Unfortunately I did not find the hint helpful since, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, one can only find a unital $\ast$-homomorphism $\varphi_n$ such that $\varphi_{n+1} \circ \lambda_n$ is unitarily equivalent to $\varphi_n$ by **Lemma 7.3.2** in the textbook. However, I do not know how to make $\varphi_{n+1}\circ \lambda_n = \varphi_n$ but once this could be proved, then I believe $B$ does not need to be AF. Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Replace $\phi_{n+1}$ with $\mathrm{Ad}(u) \circ \phi_{n+1}$ where $u$ is a unitary implementing the unitary equivalence you're describing.

Comment: The difficulty here is that the unitary given by the unitary equivalence between $\varphi_{n+1}\circ \lambda_n$ and $\varphi_n$ may depend on $n$ since what we have is that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $K_0(\varphi_{n+1}\circ \lambda_n) = K_0(\varphi_n)$.

Comment: Problem solved! Suppose $\big( A, \{\mu_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \big)$ is the inductive limit of a sequence of AF algebras $\big( \{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}, \{\lambda_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \big)$. By **Proposition 6.2.4** in the textbook, $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \mu_n(A_n)$ is a $\ast$-algebra that is dense in $A$. Next define $\varphi$ on $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \mu_n(A_n)$ by $\varphi\circ \mu_n = \varphi_n$. Then check $\varphi$ is linear, multiplicative and preserves the $\ast$-operation. Extend $\varphi$ continuously to the entire $A$ and then apply **Proposition 6.2.5** in the textbook.